# You cannot add accounts to your organization while it is initializing. Try again later

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I am trying to linked account within AWS.  But the AWS organisation throws the below error while inviting the user
" You cannot add accounts to your organization while it is initializing. Try again later"

Comment: Has the "user" accepted the invitation to join the organization? How long have you waited after accepting the invitation? How old is your AWS account?

Comment: AWS Organizations is not ready yet for prime time. I think AWS released this service before it was fully baked. The error you see is a very common error. You have to wait and try again or post in AWS forum.

Comment: @john: Invite itself getting failed.  My account is around 1 year old account.

Comment: I realize it is an old post, but still an issue: See here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251290&start=300&tstart=0

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem.  It turned out my credit card on file was expired.

Comment: Yes, My bank is start sending error response for my credit card.  Sorted out with bank. It started working.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it is fixed  itself after some hours.  It may be some sort of initialization issue that require some time to complete. You can find more information [Here](http://www.nixgyd.com/aws-cannot-add-accounts-organization-initializing/203)

Comment: In my case it was between 5-10 minutes after enabling Organizations and verifying the email address that I was able to create the first sub-account.

Answer (score 1):

Once the AWS Organization is created, you have to accept the AWS Organization Email from the Master Account, prior to sending the invite or creating child account.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it today: two things we have to check :

1. **Validate your primary email for master account, they sent verification email to your registered email id.**
2. **Check your added credit card details(in my case my card was expired so had to add it again, then it worked).**